# Best way to create a custom homepage

Tags: drupal

I'm working on creating a custom homepage in Drupal. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I was thinking on creating a custom content type called "homepage" and just edit it when needed. However, I don't know if this is really recommended or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use page content type for this and it's depend on how do you want to look this page.
Other way is theming,  for example via page-front.tpl.php, or node-page-[#NID].tpl.php, and so on. Don't forget about css styling.
If you don't want code, you can use modules Panels, Blocks, Views, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'll try the page-front.tpl!

Answer (score 3):

To create a home page that's distinctive from the rest of your site, the generally recommended approach is to create and edit a file called page-front.tpl.php within your theme directory.  See [this tutorial page](http://drupal.org/node/317461), along with the links on it regarding tips on theming, for more information.